# how to extract text until <br> tag in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to extract from div until `<br>` tag. How to do this,

For Example,

```
<div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">Watched a video that has been removed<br>Aug 17, 2018, 2:34:28 PM UTC</div>
```

I used this,

```
print  content.text
```

It outputs,

```
Watched a video that has been removedAug 17, 2018, 2:34:28 PM UTC
```

But expected output is,
    Watched a video that has been removed

I don't want a text after `<br>`

Moreover to specifically get after `<br>` I could try this,

```
content.find('br').text
```

Right now I'm thinking to do like below

```
result= (content.find('br').text).replace((content.find('br').text),'')
```

Is there any other better way to avoid my extra string replace method using beautifulsoup?

Comment: simplest might be `print soup.div.contents[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""<div class="content-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-typography--body-1">Watched a video that has been removed<br>Aug 17, 2018, 2:34:28 PM UTC</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.find("div").contents[0])
```

The output should be:

```
Watched a video that has been removed
```